# BigCommerce WebHooks API Not Working

Tags: webhooks, bigcommerce

I was able to set and get my web hooks, but nothing is posted to our system.  Here are the web hooks we have:

store/order/*
destination: "https://api.progressivepii.com"

store/order/created
destination: "https://api.progressivepii.com"

Is there a reason we're not seeing anything?  These have been posted to api.bigcommerce.com.  I have noticed that a lot of people use hooks-beta.bigcommerce.com.  Is that for live orders?  Should I be using that domain instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the hooks API and list all registered hooks to confirm if everything is in place after you have registered. Instead of registering `store/order/*` you should register individual events provided ( ie. `store/order/created` )  under the [resources](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#api-v2-documentation).

```
OAuth >GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/hooks
```

More details on how to use the webhooks API interface can be found [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#webhook-object-properties).

Comment: I used the GET to list the hooks I showed.  I _do_ have store/order/created as one of them.  Is the store/order/* in some way preventing the store/order/created hook from firing?  Should I delete the store/order/* hook?  I can retrieve orders with the GET command, I'm just not getting the hooks firing automatically.

Comment: @RandySK reconnect the app ( uninstall / install ) and then make sure your webhook returns HTTP 200 otherwise it would be discarded as unavailable.

Comment: I did that.  I have certified that I only have one webhook, the order/created one and we still don't receive posts from the webhook.  What next?